# JSDoc for object with keys that are instances of the class

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

The title might be a bit unclear, but here's a code:

**fruits.js**

```
class Fruit {
  constructor(color, taste) {
    this.color = color;
    this.taste = taste;
  }

  get fruitColor() {
    return this.color;
  }

  get fruitTaste() {
    return this.taste;
  }
}

const Fruits = {
  APPLE: new Fruit("green", "sweet"),
  LEMON: new Fruit("yellow", "sour"),
};

module.exports = { Fruits };
```

**my.class.js**

```
const { Fruits } = require("./fruits");

class MyClass {

  // I want a jsdoc here in order to get intellisense
  // and be able to have access to all fruit methods like 'fruitColor'
  getFruitColor(fruit) {
    return fruit.fruitColor;
  }

  getAppleColor() {
    return this.getFruitColor(Fruits.APPLE);
  }
}

module.exports = new MyClass();
```

**index.js** (does not actually matters in terms of the question)

```
const MyClass = require("./my.class");

const appleColor = MyClass.getAppleColor();
console.log(appleColor);
```

So I have this object `Fruits`. Each key value of it is an instance of the class Fruit (but with a different properties). When I'm passing this object's property as an argument I want to document it so I can get intellisense inside a function which accessing the 'Fruit' class methods.

Of course I don't want to hardcode it's properties because object `Fruits` can have lot's of different keys (orange, pineapple, pear etc. ).

Is ther some way to say something like:

```
/**
* @param {propertyvlaue of type Fruits}
*/
```

or

```
/**
* @param {fruit: <typeof Fruits.>}
*/
```

Or should I maybe use @typedef somewhere in `MyClass`?

**UPD:**
After trying to understand Graham P Heath answer I tried:

```
const { Fruits } = require("./fruits");

class MyClass {
  /**@param {Object.<string, Fruit>} */
  getFruitColor(fruit) {
    return fruit.fruitColor;
  }
```

But the problem is that `MyClass` does not know anything about class `Fruit` (which is the value of each key inside `Fruits` object)

Answer (score 0):

The way to indicate a type of an Object's keys is to use `Object<keyType, valueType>`. For example:

```
/** @typedef {(string|boolean)} */
const Sometype = null;

/** @type !Object<!Sometype, string> */
const objectWithCustomKeyTypes = {}

objectWithCustomKeyTypes['foo'] = 'is a string';
objectWithCustomKeyTypes[25] = 'is a number';
```

In this example, the last line throws a warning:

```
input0:8:25: WARNING - [JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH] restricted index type
found   : number
required: (boolean|string)
  8| objectWithCustomKeyTypes[25] = 'is a number';
                          ^^
```

While I've used a simple type def to demonstrate that this works with custom types, it should work with built in and third party types as well.

Ref: [Types in the Closure Type System](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System)

Comment: I tried to use `Object<>` but I guess I'm missing something. How can I let `MyClass` know what is the `Fruit` class (which is used only inside fruits.js)?

Answer (score 0):

I also came across the same problem few weeks ago and typescript has an interesting feature [ReturnType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype), make sure to check it once!

and you can change it to something like:

```
function Fruits() {
  return {
      APPLE: new Fruit("green", "sweet"),
      LEMON: new Fruit("yellow", "sour"),
  }
};
var fruit = Fruits();
fruit.APPLE //Correct
fruit.dummy //Error
```

and when you write:

```
type T4 = ReturnType<typeof Fruits>;
//will infer to on tooltip
//type T4 = {
//    APPLE: Fruit;
//    LEMON: Fruit;
//}
```

UPDATED [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiBOBXAlgF2gbwFDWsA9iPvANw7SqSoCmZuBAdhKksKsQBQFHwBc0zeMgYBzADQUq1foOEiAlJnK5UAC2QQAdN2LQAvHkLE6uCuq2Vm1fZKsmAvlnIjq6AGZI0AYSPwOi7FNoeFdEeAYzDW1fBydcF3dPVAAVKX8lIJDUMIi1KMsaWMcsN0QGNmR8CIQUVAh0wODQ8Iyg6ABBAAVOgBkAUX4GagB3OCSOACIREOoGCYkJiGHqVwn5MWVTfoBZAHkAOUGRsdrJgE9qECJh%20ehF-DC1jdxHezIsADcweGgPWpsamh6vJ3gB6UGoM4AB2syQALDYAErNBjJaHUAA8kJh%20DcJyBAD53qBIDBtmcvOAoK0EoDUD4eBw-mh%20HSAptwYYmIRqJoiCIOHTgZour0%20iDNlkcr8ktEeLFnK46akrEykqykuygpzGBAeXz8AKhf4Rd1%20hLMiiZbVNAVaORivFXO0oVCQNQGZwtaYpS08lpaUlPX5mahTWKLdBHdAEi63dQVTQGpKrf7NIHaonqGqbaLzUUnLr0GBXe7gzYhqNyZTSWRdfr%20RwS-Hg%20nnaWPb5-BL6%206DQLm2XfG3UHH3VnuyQgA)